# Angular ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in *ngFor

Tags: angular

I am getting the dreaded ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError from the following component as I am looping through a string array using *ngFor and calling a method to return a property to an input on the looped component, for example
This is my component...

```
<bike-list *ngFor="let bike of bikeList;trackBy: trackByFn"
          [label]="bike"
          [addSpacing]="true"
          [bikeColor]="getRandomBikeColor()"> <!-- <-- Here is the problem getRandomBikeColor() -->
</bike-list>
```

The method that returns a string to the `[bikeColor]` input on the component is producing the error as with each iteration it is changing the value, for example the error ready

> Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'blue'.
> Current value: 'black'

Normally to fix such an issue I would pass a local variable rather than call a method but I can't have this local var as the iteration items (the lenght of bikeList) may change in time. This is my component code...

```
export class ListBikesComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() bikes!: Bike[];

  bikeList!: string[];

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes['bikes'].currentValue) {
      this.bikeList = this.getUniqueBikeList();
    }
  }

  getUniqueBikeList(): string[] {
    return [...new Set(this.bikes?.map((bike: Bike) => bike.model))]
  }

  getRandomBikeColor(): string {
    const colors: string [] = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black', 'rusty'];
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  }

  trackByFn(index: number, bikeModel: string): number {
    // we pass index or
    return index;
  };
}
```

One thought was that I could modify my bikeList string array to an object array where each value has a random colour assigned onChanges, something like `[ { model: 'foo', color: 'whatever'}]` however this does seem like overkill. Is there a simple way for my to correctly prevent the error in the console?

Many thanks

Comment: I would suggest using a `@Input() set bikes` to set bikeList and avoid usage of `ngOnChanges`.

Comment: angular template bindings are evaluated on every change detection. I would say your code would make all elements to blink random colors on every change detection (every event that is handled by the component/app). I think that is not what you expect and constructing a `bikeList` that contains color information is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Angular will run every template expression on every change. **It will also run it one after finishing during dev mode, to check, if your application is stable**.

---

```js
export class ListBikesComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() set bikes(bikes: Bike[]) {
    this.bikeList = [...new Set(bikes?.map((bike: Bike) => bike.model))];
  }

  bikeList!: string[];

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes['bikes'].currentValue) {
      this.bikeList = this.getUniqueBikeList();
    }
  }

  getUniqueBikeList(): string[] {
    return [...new Set(this.bikes?.map((bike: Bike) => bike.model))]
  }

  private readonly bikeToColor = new WeakRef<Bike['model'], string>();
  getRandomBikeColor(bike: Bike['model']): string {
    let color = this.bikeToColor.get(bike);
    if (color) {
      return color;
    }

    const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black', 'rusty'];
    color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    this.bikeToColor.set(bike, color);
    return color;
  }
}
```